# Return list with several country names

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I would like filter two or more countries in this dataframe, but I don't know how.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEEXp.png)

```
covid.filter(items = [ 'Country', 'Confirmed', 'Deaths'] ).where(covid.Country == 'Canada').groupby('Country').max()
```

Comment: @IsaacOliveira What's your expected output?

Comment: yes, I am working with this with Pandas. I expecting input three or more country, where I cam compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Series.isin(values)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) function of pandas series to check whether values are contained in Series.

**Try this:**

```
countries = ["US", "Canada"] #--> list of countries to be included
result = (covid.filter(items=['Country', 'Confirmed', 'Deaths'])
          .where(covid["Country"].isin(countries))
          .groupby('Country')
          .max())
```

Comment: It's working. Thank you very much. I'm still learning, so I would like to get some tips from channels where I can see this, if you can indicate.

Comment: @IsaacOliveira You can always refer the official pandas docs. Or you can visit this  page `https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/tutorials.html` there are lots of tutorials and videos listed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `covid` is a Pandas dataframe. You could

```
covid.filter(items = [ 'Country', 'Confirmed', 'Deaths'] ).where(covid.Country.isin(['Canada', 'Brazil', 'US'])).groupby('Country').max()
```

Note condition `covid.Country.isin(['Canada', 'Brazil', 'US'])` in `where()`. It will match if `covid.Country` is one of the listed.

**EDIT:** Fixed code because `x in collection` wont work cause `in` will use standard python *truth-values*. For `pandas` these are considered ambiguous so you should use "bitwise" operations.